# Does a date-dependent SMS reminder with repeats reset if the date trigger is updated?

Tags: commcare

I have an SMS reminder that is set to be sent 7 days after a specific date property (let's call it "appt_date") that is saved in a form in my app that is filled in and updated every time the appointment form is filled out.

The reminder is set to repeate weekly for 12 weeks.

My question is: if a patient has an appoint 8 weeks after an appointment, and the "appt_date" property is updated, does this stop the remaining four weeks of reminders that was triggered originally and restart the count so that the patient receives a new set of 12 weeks of reminders from the new date, or do the remaining repeat weeks from the first reminder still get sent?

If it is the latter, does this mean a patient will be receiving dual messages during those overlapping 4 weeks?

Answer (score 1):

For date-triggered repeat SMS reminders, there will only be 1 active schedule.

The framework will just update the original schedule, so there's only ever one instance of that schedule for the case to which it applies. In other words, the schedule starts over for all 12 weeks with the new start date.